# can't read data field values on views from controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, view

Getting successfully the query result from db on to the view in array variable. But not able to read individual field values on views. why print_r($sales->creditofferamount) shows nothing even has data in it.
My controller:

```
    function edit($id = NULL)
{

    $id = $this->input->get('id');
    $sales = $this->Pricecomparison_model->getSalesByID($id);
    $this->data['sales'] =  $sales;
    $this->data['id'] = $id;
    $this->page_construct('pricecomparison/edit', $this->data);

}
```

View:

```
<? 
print_r($sales); //this shows all data values read from db
print_r($sales->creditofferamount);  //although this feild contain data in it but still does not show it.
?>
```

Comment: Show us `$this->Pricecomparison_model->getSalesByID($id);` function

Comment: you gave me hint and I resolved the issue. I was making mistake at model by getting value in array unnecessary.
     foreach (($q->result()) as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
   }
instead of just doing it :   return $q->row();